# How to minimize the amount of code to write when applying dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

It's annoying me for quite a while. a lot of c# features are all about reducing code and redundancies. but then we have dependency injection. And this feature requires us to specify what we want 3 times

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ServiceType _service; // first

    public MyClass(ServiceType service) // second
    {
        _service = service; // third
    }
}
```

now imagine you need to inject 10 services. have fun scrolling.

by now we have the nice pattern of initializing a class by it's public properties, we can even have init-only properties, so this pattern becomes more and more constructor-like. but of course dependency injection does not support that, as far as i know...

do you know any framework that would use that, and are there reasons why it's not yet the default DI pattern in .NET Core MVC?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public ServiceType SomeService {get; set; }
}

var property = new MyClass { SomeService = new ServiceType() };
```

can't be that difficult. just requires a bit of reflection.

Comment: I don't understand your example.  `new MyClass { SomeService = new ServiceType() }` is not dependency injection.  Are you just asking if DI can work with properties instead of constructor parameters?

Comment: I don't think the default dependency injector in .NET supports property injection, but other DI frameworks might.  It'll likely depend only partially on whether or not it's possible and more on whether or not the author thought it was the way to go.  Some would argue that constructor injection is more enforced, since there's nothing stopping consuming code from instantiating an object and not setting its properties.

Comment: Properties have a smell of just being optional but those dependencies aren't optional. Saying that you are not enforced to use the built-in di container. Just use a third party one that fits you better.

Comment: yes, i was asking that or similar, i'm happy about any pattern that reduces the 3 unneccessary parameter mentions to 1

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you would like to know whether there is a way (in C#) to minimize the amount of code (the plumbing) required in your classes while applying Dependency Injection. I believe recent C# versions do offer a solution in this regard, without having to fallback to code smells and anti-patterns.

I would like to make an important note, which is that in case you "need to inject 10 services" you are applying the Constructor Over-Injection code smell. There are many design patterns and refactorings available that help you to avoid creating classes with more than four or five dependencies. I'd go into too much detail here to discuss the problems and solutions surrounding Constructor Over-Injection. Instead, I'd like to refer to section 6.1 of my book, [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://cuttingedge.it/book). My experience, though, is that with four or five dependencies, the amount of 'cruft' caused by DI is workable.

You suggested the use of [Property Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-property-injection/) as a solution to minimize the cruft that is caused by enabling loose coupling. Property Injection, however, causes the [temporal coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) design smell, even in the case of init-only properties. And besides that, the underlying problem of Constructor Over-Injection is that the class has too many dependencies; it's likely violating the [Single-Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). The use of Property Injection doesn't change that fact. Property Injection is, therefore, not advised over Constructor Injection.

Instead, C# 9 introduced the concept of [Record types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) which allow a superior method of reducing cruft, without having to resort to code smells such as temporal coupling. Using the record-type syntax of C# 9, your `MyClass` example can be reduced to the following:

```cs
public record MyClass(ServiceType service)
{
}
```

In case `MyClass` has five dependencies, it could look as follows:

```cs
public record MyClass(
    IOrderRepository repository,
    IMessageService messageService,
    IBillingSystem billingSystem,
    ILocationService locationService,
    IInventoryManagement inventoryManagement)    
{
}
```

A record type contains its dependencies in its definition and the C# compiler will automatically generate (among other things) a constructor, (public) members for your dependencies and assignments for you. This means that it still is impossible to create the type without the required dependencies (which is an important feature of Constructor Injection).

> **UPDATE:** C# 12 adds [Primary Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#primary-constructors) to classes. This allows the same syntax as above but with 'plain old classes' instead, which means the C# compiler doesn't generate as much code behind the scenes to enable value-type semantics.

The most important downside (IMO) is the lack of precondition checking such as null checks. It is possible to inject `null` values into `MyClass` (by calling `new MyClass(null)`, which could have been prevented when implementing the constructor by hand. To me, however, this is a small price to pay, especially if you're using a DI Container that prevents `null` from being injected. A future version of C# might overcome this shortcoming when it allows generating null checks based on a short-hand syntax. Such feature, unfortunately, got delayed several times in the past. It's unclear when this feature will be added to the language.

Comment: okay, this is quite funny because i just recently had a question about those records and the outcome: don't use it for services.

however i'm usually the last one to care. however, the record method has one very important downside. it can't derive from classes. so in MVC it wouldn't work for controllers, because the ControllerBase is a class. 

so, imagine a controller needs 2 repositories. e.g. one to fetch your apllication configuration and one to fetch a specific model, you'd still want to use dependency injection.

what do you do?

Comment: You are right about the limitation of inheriting from base classes. Most of your application components will (and should) not derive from base classes, so this is a limitation that will only affect a few parts, such as when writing MVC controller classes. The only 'solution' I have in this regard is: just fall back to regular classes for this case and implement the constructor yourself. As I said in my answer, application components shouldn't get that many dependencies anyway.

Comment: true, but the constructor is the entry point of you application and the point which is most likely to get the most dependencies. imagine you have a config repository, a desktop repository and the desktop being a repository for desktop-booking, if you configuration gets too complex you could have different levels of config repositories like provider config repository, parameter config repository and user settings repository, which could all potentially be used by a controller. but maybe in a later c# version we will get a solution...

Comment: Hi @Kyoshiro, I'm afraid I didn't understand your last comment. What do you mean by "the constructor is the entry point of you[r] application"? I would also like to stress that I always succeeded in keeping the number of dependencies low in my controllers, and I would advise you to do the same. There are many patterns and practices that can help in this regard. You can think about applying the Facade Service refactoring, apply messaging patterns, use decorators for cross-cutting concerns, split big controllers into smaller ones. Many of those options are discussed in my book (see 6.1 and 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can minimize the amount of code using `required` properties with `Autofac 7.0`.

> From Autofac 7.0 onwards, for reflection components, all required properties are automatically resolved at the time of object construction, and are generally treated in much the same way as mandatory constructor arguments.

Example:

```cs
public class MyComponent
{
    // This will be automatically injected.
    public required ILogger Logger { protected get; init; }

    // This will be automatically injected.
    public required IConfigReader ConfigReader { protected get; init; }

    public IDatabaseContext Context { get; set; }
}
```

You can find more info here:
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#required-properties